# Set cookies to display new stylesheet but url domain name change

Tags: jquery, cookies

here's my delima and i hope someone with some good skills can resolve this. I'm running a script so that users can switch between a fixed and full view of the website. I set cookies to remember their preference , which is working fine. However the main site resides on a domain called:  www.mysite.com

while  all the linked pages reside on the subdomain:  pages.mysite.com

So when you click full view while visiting www.mysite.com , and then go to any pages residing on pages.mysite.com  , you have to reset to full view again before your cookies will set that view as well.

Maybe that's all that can be done, but i'm wanting to ask if anyone knows a solution. Here is my script. The script is set as a header message on the main domain and the subdomain pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($j) {
        switch_style = {
            onReady: function () {
                this.switch_style_click();
            },
            switch_style_click: function () {
                var cookieValue = getCookie('mflSkinId');
                if (cookieValue != null) {
                    switch_style.set_style(cookieValue);
                }

                $(".skin").click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");

                    setCookie('mflSkinId', id, 1000);
                    switch_style.set_style(id);
                });
            },
            set_style: function (id) {
                $("#switch_style").attr("href", "2014/MFL_Skins/" + id + ".css");
            }
        };
        $j().ready(function () {
            switch_style.onReady();
        });
    });

    function setCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function deleteCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can associate a cookie with a parent domain, so set the domain of the cookie to `.mysite.com` instead of defailting it to the domain of the page.

Comment: Ty Barmar , can you illustrate that, unfortunately I have to google and use stack to get anything done , still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setCookie` function, specify the domain option when creating the cookie, and set it to the parent domain:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/; domain=.mysite.com";
}
```

Comment: I tired that , seems like it should work but it doesn't , the main domain is www.myfantasyfootball.com and the subs are football.myfantasyleague.com   , so setting the path to the parent domain myfantasyleague.com should have worked but alas ..... is it possible to set the cookie for both domain names at the same time ?

Comment: The two domains aren't in the same parent domain.

Comment: You can only set a cookie for your own domain or parent, not an unrelated domain.

Comment: the header response from both domains are showing me this  domain=.myfantasyleague.com; , when i view in developer tools

Comment: If the domain isn't a parent of the current domain, it's ignored.

Comment: ty for the assistance , your answer was correct if i had the right question lol

Comment: It was correct for the question you wrote, since you said both pages were subdomains of `mysite.com`.

Comment: Got it working now , i removed the ";" you had shown behind the .com and it works fine.  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/; domain=.mysite.com";